# I'm getting an error after running the command "git push -u origin master"

Tags: git

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/abyss_monarch/git-test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: The error message shows your options. Just pull, make sure your changes isn't overwritten, and push again.

Comment: Search for the error message on google. Searching on StackOverflow alone : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do

Answer (score 1):

It's better to read git documentation first.
Here is the link: [https://git-scm.com/docs/git]

At first, you need to git pull to update your local repository with remote repository, There maybe some changes on remote.
So you do this command first:

> git pull origin master

and then

> git push origin master

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

As git says in the error message, you don't have the latest revision from origin. You have to pull and merge before you can push. To do this, do
`git pull origin`

Hope this helps. Regards.
APS